# how to upload a file in java

Tags: java, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to upload files in JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet)

In my JSP page I have a field for choosing files, as follows:

```
   <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile">
```

And in my action page, I am getting this file as follows:

```
   File fileUpload=request.getAttribute("fileUpload");

   String fileName="uploadedfile.jpg";
   File target=new File("D:\\",fileName);
   FileUtils.copyFile(file,target);
```

by using the above code I can upload the file in the named uploadedfile.jpg.But i want to get the file name and type of the uploaded file dynamically from the chosen file.How can i get it?

Comment: I should point out that the code in your question doesn't upload anything.  In fact, all it appears to be doing is copying a file from one place on the server to another place on the server.  (Without doing any checks ... which makes it a security hole.)

Answer (score 2):

Apache Commons FileUpload can do what you want to, and more:

http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/

Some relevant methods in the `FileItem` class:

```
getSize() 
          Returns the size of the file item.

getContentType() 
          Returns the content type passed by the browser or null if not defined.
```

http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/index.html